# tabControl itemsize according to filename

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I please need assistance with tabcontrol itemsize. (winforms)

I have a owner-drawn tabcontrol and all working fine. Itemsize is set to width of 0 and sizemode to fixed in the tabcontrol properties. When I open a filename eg test.txt then "button" looks something like this

```
|test123.txt    | 
|Untitled    |
```

which is fine, however, if I open longer filenames then the "button" looks like this

```
|thisisaverylongfilename.txt                             |
|anotherlongname.txt                              |
```

I'm trying to make the "button" so that the filename just fits with some space on the right and the space should be the same for all.

Below is my code for the user drawn tabcontrol

```
        Image cross = imageList1.Images[0];
        int xWidth = cross.Width;

        TabPage tp = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

        Size size = tabControl1.ItemSize;

        Font fntTab;
        Brush bshBack;
        Brush bshFore;

        if (e.Index == this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            fntTab = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8.0F, FontStyle.Regular);
            bshBack = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(e.Bounds, Color.FromName(tabpages_primary_backcolor), Color.FromName(tabpages_secondary_backcolor), System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.BackwardDiagonal);
            bshFore = Brushes.Firebrick;
        }
        else
        {
            fntTab = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8.0F, FontStyle.Regular);

            bshBack = new SolidBrush(Color.Empty);
            bshFore = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        }

        string tabName = this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text;
        StringFormat sftTab = new StringFormat();
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bshBack, e.Bounds);
        Rectangle recTab = e.Bounds;
        recTab = new Rectangle(recTab.X + 5, recTab.Y + 4, recTab.Width, recTab.Height - 4);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tabName, fntTab, bshFore, recTab, sftTab);


        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab != null)
        {
            currentCrossRect = new Rectangle(
            e.Bounds.Left + size.Width - 22, 3, xWidth, xWidth);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(cross, currentCrossRect.X - 2, currentCrossRect.Y + 2);
        }
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: Yes sorry - I meant owner-drawn and it is for winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Get the width of the text using:

```
SizeF s = e.Graphics.MeasureString(myString, myFont);
```

And then you can set the item's width to s.Width!

Comment: Hi Galister. I had a look at measurestring before I posted this question, however, I'm not pretty sure where in my code to set the width to s.Width as the width is obtained from the tabcontrol properties. If I add

    tabControl1.ItemSize = new size(s.Width, 25)

the tab button flickers non stop without any change in width.